# Showing that $f_k \rightarrow f $ uniformly on $A$ $\iff f_k \rightarrow f $ in $ C_b $

Tags: real-analysis

If $(M,d)$, and $(N,p)$ are metric spaces, $A \subset M$ and $C_b= \{ f: A \rightarrow N \mid f \text{ is bounded and continuous}\},$ equipped with the sup norm then my analysis textbook claims

$f_k \rightarrow f $ uniformly on $A$ $\iff f_k \rightarrow f $ in $ C_b $. I am having trouble with the forward direction. First of all does $f_k \rightarrow f $ in $C_b$ mean that the $f_k$, and $f$ are in $C_b$, or rather that only necessarily $f \in C_b$.

Also is it not possible for a sequence of functions to converge uniformly to a function that is neither bounded nor continuous? This theorem almost seems wrong to me I must be missing something important, but I have checked the conditions for both directions several times.

Edit: My mistake, it seems I missed the $f_k$ are continuous.

Comment: Are you sure that '$f \in A$' is correct? You later say that the functions 'converge uniformly on A'. Perhaps $C_b$ is the spaces of functions $A \longrightarrow N$ that are continuous and bounded?

Comment: @GuidoA. right will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems wrong. For example, the sequence in $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$
f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}x
$$

converges uniformly to $0$. However, if we now define

$$
g_n(x) = \cases{0 \quad \quad \text{ if } x = 1 \\ f_n(x) \text{ otherwise}}
$$

we still have uniform convergence: $g_n \to 0$ uniformly but $g_n \not \in C_b$ for all $n > 1$. What is true, however, is that if $N$ is complete then $C_b$ is closed, that is, whenever $(f_n)_{n \geq 1} \subseteq C_b$ converge to a certain function $f \in N^A$, we have $f \in C_b$.

Comment: I think I missed the assumption that the $f_k$ are continuous. Sorry about that, I will still accept this answer and study it.